# Store result of JS function in variable when function is run first time - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a custom JavaScript variable for Google Tag Manager, and I can't seem to get the functions to run in the right order...

(As seen below:)

This is a chunk of code that was created to check whether an email form was filled out correctly or not. ValidateForm() is run when the user has entered their name and email address, and hit the 'send' button (the function EmailCheck checks whether the email address is valid or not). ValidateForm will then return either true or false. When ValidateForm evaluates to true AND the user has hit the 'send' button, I want to send an event to Google Analytics.

My approach has been to try and store the result of ValidateForm in a variable *when it's run the first time*, so that my additional anonymous function will evaluate to true, but I can't seem to get the syntax right and now I'm doubting this is even possible (?).

My other idea was to just run the anonymous function on onload, but that will never evaluate to true since ValidateForm is not run until the user has entered their details and hit the 'send' button... How do I make this right? Any help appreciated :)

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var emailID = document.cpren.email
    if ((emailID.value == null) || (emailID.value == '')) {
        alert('Please enter a valid email address')
        emailID.focus()
        return false;
    }
    if (EmailCheck(emailID.value) == false) {
        emailID.value = ""
        emailID.focus()
        return false;


        }
 return true;

}

    //anonymous function
function () { 
    var result  = //the result of ValidateForm when it was run when user hit the 'send' button
    if (result) {
        return = "checkedOutTrue"
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think you essentially want to validate your form.  To do this part I would just use a standard Custom HTML tag which is fired on page load (DOM ready probably).  If you want to be able to fire certain tags when a valid (or invalid) form is submitted, then you should push custom events on to the dataLayer as appropriate.

You probably want to do the following, create a new custom HTML tag with the following code.  This code will bind a function to the 'submit' event of your form:

```
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(){
      function ValidateForm(){
        var emailID = document.cpren.email;
        if ((emailID.value == null) || (emailID.value == '') || EmailCheck(emailID.value) == false) {
          alert('Please enter a valid email address');
          emailID.focus();
          dataLayer.push({'event':'form-submitted', 'status':'fail', 'error':'invalid email'});
          return false;
        }else{
          dataLayer.push({'event':'form-submitted', 'status':'success'});
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
```

With this code, you always get a custom event in the dataLayer to tell you when a form has been submitted and you then have dataLayer items to tell you the status of the submission and an error code if it's failed.

You can then build a trigger to fire off of the form-submitted event and populate variables to understand the status and then fire tags accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I am finding with custom javascript variables in GTM is that they are executed at all phases during the page load.  Not just on the triggers where you want them to be executed and the order that they are executed cannot even be set.
So I think you will need to re-evaluate your approach.